# CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied warning

Tags: ios, iphone

I am working on a simple tab based application. While running this app, I am getting the following warning logged in my xcode,

```
CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: , or invalid scale factor: 2.000000
```

I am setting tab item images using [UIImage imageNamed:@""] because my images are not yet ready. Is it the reason for this warning?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it is on topic, and the answer as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may happen when try to load unknown image. Please check a correct image name is passed for imageName

```
[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]
```